# Can't set background image for android

Tags: android, eclipse, background

I have a problem for set an image in background. I use background tag but there is an error I don't understand! see below pictures.

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

Comment: the full error is cut in the screenshot you supplied. can you either fix the screenshot or copy paste the full error message here?

Comment: do you have the  drawable in the drawable folder?

Comment: do a project->clean and see if the problem is solved.

Comment: Is splash_drawable xml file ? @Jamshid

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes resources get out of sync with the file system. Do a refresh (select project in resource explorer and press F5).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following tips.

1. Resize the background image in to a smaller resolution and size.
2. Use only *.PNG images.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your project from `Project>Clean..`